# Clearing a ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have tried all the possible ways to clear the data inside a combo box, but surprisingly nothing is working.

I want my `combobox1` to load some value into `combobox2` in the selected index of `combobox1` changes. The values are loaded, but when I move to the next index I have written this code:

```
if (SView._StudentSchool_.Equals("Pre-School")) 
{               
    TB.TimeBlock("Pre-School");
    comboBox3.Enabled = true;
    comboBox3.Items.Clear();

    for (int i = 1; i < TB.i+1; i++) 
    {
        comboBox3.Items.Add(TB.TimeBlock_[j]);
        j++;
    } 
}
else if (SView._StudentSchool_.Equals("Kindergarten")) 
{                 
    TB.TimeBlock("Kindergarten");
    comboBox3.Enabled = true;
    comboBox3.Items.Clear();

    for (int i = 1; i < TB.i + 1; i++)
    {
        comboBox3.Items.Add(TB.TimeBlock_[j]);
        j++;
    }
}
else if (SView._StudentSchool_.Equals("Primary School")) 
{
    TB.TimeBlock("Primary School");
    comboBox3.Enabled = true;
    comboBox3.Items.Clear();

    for (int i = 1; i < TB.i + 1; i++)
    {
        comboBox3.Items.Add(TB.TimeBlock_[j]);
        j++;
    } 
}
```

The `Clear()` function is not working, neither do the other methods like `.datasourse = null` or `.Text = ""` or removing items using a loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < comboBox3.Items.Count; i++)
{
    comboBox3.Items.RemoveAt(i);
    i--;
}
```

Comment: FYI -- `comboBox1`, `comboBox2`, & `comboBox3` are terrible names.

Comment: what is the behavior of `Combobox3` when this code excutes.it adds the items to existing list or it has only previous items?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you've stepped into this with the debugger and `comboBox3` is, in fact, not cleared after calling `.Clear()`?

Comment: it is not clearing just adds up new items

Comment: Since you mention `.DataSource` in your question, is `comboBox3` data-bound?

Comment: no I just meant I did whatever I could but nothing is clearing it.

Comment: My question still holds -- have you stepped through this with a debugger and confirmed that `.Clear()` has no effect after it's been called?  If not, then there's a good chance `TB.TimeBlock` is not working as you expect.

Comment: TB.TimeBlock contents are added up to the combobox, the previous items are not removed. this is the problem

Comment: Are the previous items also in `TB.TimeBlock_`???

Comment: No, I checked in console mode the returned values are fine

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that your combobox DropDownStyle property is set to DropDown.
In that case you need to call

```
comboBox3.Items.Clear();
comboBox3.ResetText();
comboBox3.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

If you have the property set to DropDownStyle simply calling Items.Clear shoud be enough

If you have set the DataSource somewhere in your code the [Microsoft Support describes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/327895) a different approach to clear the items, first subscribe the event DataSourceChanged then call

```
comboBox3.DataSource = null;
```

The code for the event should be

```
private void comboBox3_DataSourceChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox ctb = (ComboBox) sender;
    if (ctb.DataSource == null)
        ctb.Items.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Do you have set somewhere the DataSource property?

Comment: no when the selected index changes the new items are added up, the clear function doesn't work.

Comment: However the behavior you describe is typical when there is a DataSource set. In that case the MSDN describes a different approach. Updating the answer

Answer (score 1):

This is too large for a comment so it's a CW answer...

Based on what you've shown, you don't need 3 if-statements if you do this:

```
        TB.TimeBlock(SView._StudentSchool_);
        comboBox3.Enabled = true;
        comboBox3.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 1; i < TB.i + 1; i++)
        {
            comboBox3.Items.Add(TB.TimeBlock_[j]);
            j++;
        }
```

Comment: No, I making so many sql queries, it can't be done this way.

Comment: @PouyaV.. -- Wow.  Fail.  If you can justify that statement in _any way_, I will be impressed.  SQL queries have no bearing on whether code can be generalized as functions.

Comment: The way I have designed my database is not standard I just did fast, there is no normalization, ... it is working anyway but not the combo box

Comment: I am getting some value from one table then check it in another table and I'm interpreting those as only three items

Comment: @Pouya are you familiar with the term `Garbage in Equals Garbage Out` if you do a half @$$ job of creating something how do you expect 100% proper functionality..?

Answer (score 1):

> I want my combobox1 to load some value into **combobox2**

I don't know if this was a typo, but you might be looking at the wrong combobox.

Comment: +1 and if this is right, kudos to you and my comment on terrible names holds truer than ever.

Comment: @AustinSalonen I noticed this at the very beginning but after I saw all the good solutions didn't work for Pouya, then I realized this seems very likely to be the problem.